# Is it possible to do a npm start when the project directory is in host machine?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, virtualbox

I have a virtual box with windows 10 installed on it, I added the folder which contains my React app to virtual box shared folders, after that I went inside the virtual box and mounted the shared folder as a drive, now after I open the React app project with vs code inside my virtual box and in the terminal I type
`npm start`
I get the error :

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Starting the development server...

node:events:356
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, watch 'Z:\myReactApp\public'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (node:internal/fs/watchers:219:26)
    at Object.watch (node:fs:1572:34)
    at createFsWatchInstance (Z:\myReactApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (Z:\myReactApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (Z:\myReactApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (Z:\myReactApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (Z:\myReactApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (Z:\myReactApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:195:5)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (Z:\myReactApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:260:10)     
    at createFsWatchInstance (Z:\myReactApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:40:5)
    at setFsWatchListener (Z:\myReactApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:195:5) {
  errno: -4068,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'EISDIR',
  path: 'Z:\\myReactApp\\public',
  filename: 'Z:\\myReactApp\\public'
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path Z:\myReactApp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c react-scripts start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-20T15_32_54_716Z-debug.log
```

Why is this error happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Some dependencies might be platform-dependent. I would at least run `npm ci` in the virtual machine first.

Comment: @bodo, Removing node modules and using npm install or using npm ci, all of them have different errors, I was really hoping to be able to work directly on my the project while its still on my host .., any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to it ?

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez No, but i found another way which served my purpose, i run my project and then i go to virtual box, connect to kerio and finally use the local ip to see the result of the web i have in main PC, this helped me because i was trying to run npm in virtual box so i don't have to connect and disconnect kerio each time i want to work on my project.